# AppStore Connect should Unrestricted Web Access be turned on?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

Do i need to select YES to unrestricted Web Access if i use a WKWebView that ONLY allows one website to be displayed to the user? I have set up that they can't browse another website than one I decided.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, then you don't need to click this setting, I've created an app that can access all websites even http and I've selected this, the app got a high age rating but got approved.

Be sure that the user cannot hop from that one site to others like if it were a search engine.

Comment: No they can't. I am reassured. Thanks